# Why is the electric field outside a dielectric used to calculate the polarization vector?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am working through Griffiths Electrodynamics and am having trouble reasoning through a step in example 4.8. More specifically, I do not understand whether to use the electric field outside or inside the dielectric when calculating the polarization vector.

In this example the entire region below z = 0 is filled with a uniform linear dielectric of susceptibility $ \chi_e $. A point charge q is situated a distance d above the origin and we must calculate the force on this charge.

He proceeds to calculate the bound surface charge $\sigma_b = \mathbf{P} \cdot \hat{n} = \epsilon_0 \chi_e E_z$. He substitutes $E_z =  \frac{-1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac {q}{r^2 + d^2} cos \theta - \frac{ \sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$ into the equation so that

$$ \sigma_b = \epsilon_o \chi_e (\frac{-1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac {qd}{(r^2 + d^2)^{3/2}} - \frac{ \sigma}{2\epsilon_0})$$

Then solves for $\sigma_b$. In this case he is using $E_\perp$ outside the dielectric. I am unable to justify this approach and would appreciate if someone could provide a reason for using the electric field outside the dielectric rather then inside when calculating the polarization vector. Moreover, there intuitively seems to be an iterative effect where the electric field influences the polarization which then influences the electric field. Why is it the case that we can simply use the electric field outside the dielectric without worrying about this?[image]